# How can I mark and choose several of my items to my next tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I  created a tableview and got a list of items then how can I mark and choose several of them to my next tableview?

Answer (score 0):

you can store your got list as a NSMutableArray . And then make the mutableArray as the dataSource of the next tableView.